# Create a table with the values of 3 strings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL (T-SQL) I have 3 lists of numbers, in the form of strings (I take them from an Excel file):

```
DECLARE @article_list VARCHAR(MAX) = 1060226, 20653, 39986, 1041443, 1060303, 1057353, 1050423, 1057354, 1059541, 1050570';
DECLARE @store_list VARCHAR(MAX) = '1046, 1046, 1046, 1046, 1107, 1107, 1107, 1107, 1107, 1107';
DECLARE @order_list VARCHAR(MAX) = '1012406, 2008322, 2008322, 2008322, 2011092, 1020199, 1020199, 1020199, 1020176, 2010731';
```

And I want to create a table like this:

```
DECLARE @rows_to_delete TABLE (rn INT IDENTITY(1,1), art INT, ord INT, stor INT);
```

Now I need to load the values of the lists, in the same order, into the table @rows_to_delete, like `{1060226, 1046, 1012406}, {20653, 1046, 2008322}`
(it's not JSON, I just want to describe the table rows..)

Any ideas?

Comment: There are plenty of string splitters that provide the original position of the value, including the built in function (in 2022+), what's wrong with all of those? What splitter did you try? Why didn't your attempt(s) work?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` using the `enable_ordinal` paramter

Answer (score 5):

Here is a JSON based solution, using set based operations.

It will work starting from SQl Server 2016 onwards.

We are converting input strings into JSON arrays with guaranteed sequential order. `OPENJSON()` is converting JSON arrays into rectangular data sets with [Key] and [Value] columns.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @rows_to_delete TABLE (rn INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, art INT, ord INT, stor INT);

DECLARE @article_list VARCHAR(MAX) = '1060226, 20653, 39986, 1041443, 1060303, 1057353, 1050423, 1057354, 1059541, 1050570'
    , @store_list VARCHAR(MAX) = '1046, 1046, 1046, 1046, 1107, 1107, 1107, 1107, 1107, 1107'
    , @order_list VARCHAR(MAX) = '1012406, 2008322, 2008322, 2008322, 2011092, 1020199, 1020199, 1020199, 1020176, 2010731';
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH art AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON('[' + @article_list + ']') 
), ord AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON('[' + @order_list + ']')  
), stor AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON('[' + @store_list + ']')  
)
INSERT @rows_to_delete (art, ord, stor)
SELECT art.Value, ord.Value, stor.Value
FROM art 
    INNER JOIN ord ON ord.[Key] = art.[Key]
    INNER JOIN stor ON stor.[Key] = art.[Key]
ORDER BY art.[Key];

-- test
SELECT * FROM @rows_to_delete ORDER BY rn;
```

**Output**

| rn | art | ord | stor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1060226 | 1012406 | 1046 |
| 2 | 20653 | 2008322 | 1046 |
| 3 | 39986 | 2008322 | 1046 |
| 4 | 1041443 | 2008322 | 1046 |
| 5 | 1060303 | 2011092 | 1107 |
| 6 | 1057353 | 1020199 | 1107 |
| 7 | 1050423 | 1020199 | 1107 |
| 8 | 1057354 | 1020199 | 1107 |
| 9 | 1059541 | 1020176 | 1107 |
| 10 | 1050570 | 2010731 | 1107 |

Comment: the same thing applies to OPENJSON, the order can be random.

Comment: Directly the opposite. The `OPENJSON()` guarantees the sequential order.

Comment: *"When OPENJSON parses a JSON array, the function returns the indexes of the elements in the JSON text as keys."* As seen in the Microsoft official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: yes, you are right. Please make a small edit and I will remove my downvote. You didn't use the order by but instead joined on keys, which I missed in the first scan.

Comment: The `Key` ordering in the joins is perfectly valid and the results are deterministic.  However (and not that it really matters in this case), the `rn` assignments in the `@rows_to_delete` might not be, unless you add a final `ORDER BY art.[Key]` or similar. Likely *not observable* unless the data grows large enough that SQL server starts using hash table lookups or partitions the work into parallel operations that might have an indeterminant order when merged.

Answer (score 2):

If looking for a little more brevity.

```
DECLARE @article_list VARCHAR(MAX) = '1060226, 20653, 39986, 1041443, 1060303, 1057353, 1050423, 1057354, 1059541, 1050570'
      , @store_list   VARCHAR(MAX) = '1046, 1046, 1046, 1046, 1107, 1107, 1107, 1107, 1107, 1107'
      , @order_list   VARCHAR(MAX) = '1012406, 2008322, 2008322, 2008322, 2011092, 1020199, 1020199, 1020199, 1020176, 2010731';

 Insert Into @rows_to_delete
 Select art  = A.Value
       ,ord  = O.Value
       ,stor = S.Value
  From OPENJSON('[' + @article_list + ']')  A
  Join OPENJSON('[' + @store_list + ']')    S on A.[Key]=S.[key]
  Join OPENJSON('[' + @order_list + ']')    O on A.[Key]=O.[key]
```